# order function: given the order of a vector and the ordered vector, how can I get original vector?

Tags: r

Consider a vector `x`:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
```

We can get the order of `x` and the ordered `x` with:

```
y <- order(x)
z <- x[y]
```

If I only kown `y` and `z`, how can I get original `x`?

Comment: @mt1022; Actually, the more typical way of getting an ordered x would be to leave out the second `order` operation. Your version doesn't actually result in a properly ordered z.

Comment: And if you actually had `z <- x[y]` to get `x` you can similarly do: `z[order(y)]`

Comment: @42-. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
The old solution (to the original question) is:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- order(x)
z <- x[order(y)]
x2 <- z[y]
identical(x2, x)
```

Since the question now states the `z` as:

```
y <- order(x)
z <- x[y]
```

The answer is obviously (as in @Rohit's answer):

```
x2<-numeric(length(x))
x2[y]<-z
identical(x2, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial way of doing things is wrong as @42 said. The correct way of sorting x is:

```
y<-order(x)
z<-x[y]
```

Then you can get back the original x as:

```
x2<-numeric(length(x))
x2[y]<-z
identical(x2, x)
```

Comment: According to OPs question, they did not want to do it this way. They may have intended to ask the question slightly differently but we can't know for sure. Maybe best to include as a comment

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my original question. As commented by 42- and Mike, my original code was wrong and I have updated it.